# how to get count Of Product according Store

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three Table : `Product` and `StoreDetail`  , `Store`
`Store` Table holds `storeName` .
I want get count of product according storeName , to do this I use belowe code :

```
 var stocksQuery = storeDetails.GroupBy(row => new { row.StoreId, row.ProductId }).AsQueryable();

        List<StockStatusViewModel> result = new List<StockStatusViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in stocksQuery)
        {
            result.Add(new StockStatusViewModel
            {
                Quantity = item.Sum(row => row.Quantity),
                ProductCombinationId = item.Key.ProductAttributeCombinationId,
                StoreId = item.Key.StoreId,
                // here I need productName and StoreName
            });

        }
```

but I need to storeName and ProductName , how can I get these ?
here Is my classes:

```
 public class StoreDetail 
{
    public Product Product{ get; set; }
    public  Guid ProductId { get; set; }
 }

 public class Product{
 public  ICollection<StoreDetail> StoreDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any relationship between Store and StoreDetails table?

Comment: @Edward  yes , each store have many storeDetail

Comment: So in the StoreDetail model, do you have a properties Store (it's relationship to Store table, kind of foreign key)?

Comment: @Edward yes I have `StoreId ` and another , but I dont put all of them here .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try some thing like this, instead of group by **StoredId** and **ProductId**, I will group by **Store** and **Product**

```
var stocksQuery = storeDetails.GroupBy(row => new { row.Store, row.Product }).AsQueryable();

        List<StockStatusViewModel> result = new List<StockStatusViewModel>();
        foreach (var item in stocksQuery)
        {
            result.Add(new StockStatusViewModel
            {
                Quantity = item.Sum(row => row.Quantity),
                ProductCombinationId = item.Key.ProductAttributeCombinationId,
                StoreId = item.Key.StoreId,
                StoreName = item.Key.Store.StoreName,
                ProductName = item.Key.Product.ProductName
            });

        }
```

For better performance, I think we just select what we need so we can change the code to

```
var stocksQuery = storeDetails.GroupBy(row => new { row.StoreId, row.Store.StoreName, row.ProductId, row.Product.ProductName }).AsQueryable();

            List<StockStatusViewModel> result = new List<StockStatusViewModel>();
            foreach (var item in stocksQuery)
            {
                result.Add(new StockStatusViewModel
                {
                    Quantity = item.Sum(row => row.Quantity),
                    ProductCombinationId = item.Key.ProductAttributeCombinationId,
                    StoreId = item.Key.StoreId,
                    StoreName = item.Key.StoreName,
                    ProductName = item.Key.ProductName
                });

            }
```